# Calculating distance metrics between a sample set and a point

Tags: classification, text-mining, distance-functions, feature-engineering

i have a list of text files and i know that these texts belong to a group, by using this group of text files (i.e this is my sample set) i'd like to calculate [Jaccard index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) and [Edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) for each text file that are not in the sample set. By doing so i'd like to generate two features of each text file which are the similarity/diversity of each file from the sample set of text files. After constructing my dataset, classification will be used.

how can i achieve this? Problem arises when i try to calculate Jaccard index and Edit distance for each text file. i'm not sure i should calculate the Jaccard index and Edit distance for each text in sample set and take the average of them and use these as a feature, this can be computationally inefficient.

P.S: my reputation is too low that i couldn't create the tags of jaccard-index, edit-distance,similarity and divergence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely your sample set contains the correct classification for each sample in the form $\{x_{i},y_{i}\}$, with $x_{i}$ as a text document and $y_{i}$ as its classification.

Therefore, one approach you may want to explore is to determine a set of important words for your data set. Let's suppose you choose 100 words. Then you can create a list of 0's and 1's for each document in your sample set in order to create a $N \times M$ matrix where $N$ is the number of documents and $M$ the number of important words (in this case 100). Assign $0$ in the appropriate column to the document whenever that word doesn't appear in that document and $1$ otherwise.

Now you compare your test document to each sample document and calculate a Jaccard coefficient. Finally, assign the class of the sample document to the test document for which the Jaccard coefficient is closest to $1$. It seems to me that is the simplest equivalent to the KNN algorithm (with $K=1$).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) and the [single linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering) clustering algorithm.